# Sorting 2d Integers Array Java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

i have an 2d Array which is [2][10]. It is filled with random numbers.
Could someone please help me how to sort it? I dont know why but any found way to sort it with Comparator doesnt work for me. So im trying to do that in a loop. It has to be sorted by the column.

Im trying to play with creating a temporary array and inserting the value into it, but i dont know how to compare values: [0][0] and [0][1].
My try is do 2 for loops and inside it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr4.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < arr4[i].length; j++) {
        if(arr4[i][j] > ???????)
    temparray = arr4[i][j];
    }
 }
```

Help me please...

Comment: Please provide sample test case and expected output for that test case.

Comment: Do you want to sort by row order or column order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need to sort line by line you need to update your solution like this

```
  for (int i = 0; i < arr4.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < arr4[i].length-1; j++) {
            if(arr4[i][j] > arr4[i][j+1]){
              temparray = arr4[i][j];
              arr4[i][j] = arr4[i][j+1]
              arr4[i][j+1] = temparray  ;
              j=0;
          }
        }
     }


input:
[1.0, 2.0]
[6.0, 4.0]
[5.0, 4.0]
```

output:

```
[1.0, 2.0]
[4.0, 6.0]
[4.0, 5.0]
```